# Why does R plot_ly 3D plot with small alpha change color?

Tags: r, plotly

Have a look at those plots:

```
library(plotly)
plot_ly(iris, x=~Sepal.Width, y=~Sepal.Length, color = ~Petal.Width)
plot_ly(iris, x=~Sepal.Width, y=~Sepal.Length, z=~Petal.Length, color = ~Petal.Width)
plot_ly(iris, x=~Sepal.Width, y=~Sepal.Length, color = ~Petal.Width, alpha = .2)
plot_ly(iris, x=~Sepal.Width, y=~Sepal.Length, z=~Petal.Length, color = ~Petal.Width, alpha = .2)
```

[image: 2dnoalpha]

[image: 3dnoalpha]

[image: 2dwithalpha]

[image: 3dwithalpha]

You can see that only the last plot stands out. Why is that? What can I do about it?